# How to set timeout to JAX-RS client with CXF

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf, httpclient

I am working on a Rest Client and I am using **CXF** with **JAX-RS**.

The problem that I have is that I cannot find any way to override the default timeout values of the client.

**A simple client:**

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/MyApp");
target = target.path("jsp/Test.jsp");
Response response = target.request().get();
```

I have read that there are two timeout properties in **CXF** called `ReceiveTimeout` and `ConnectionTimeout` but I have not managed to find a way to set them in my client.

I have tried `client.property("ReceiveTimeout", 5000);` but it doesn't work.

I have seen examples of using an **xml** configuration file to configure the client but I prefer not to take that path if it is possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(30000);
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

see http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transports/http/configuration/HTTPClientPolicy.html

Comment: There is no `getConduit()` method in the `javax.ws.rs.client.Client`. Can you provide more details on the client object?

Comment: Sorry, try using cxf's WebClient https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/WebClient.html Example here http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/apache-cxf/systests/jaxrs/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/jaxrs/JAXRSClientServerResourceCreatedSpringProviderTest.java.shtml

Comment: Is there any way to set these parameters without using propietary CXF classes (even if CXF is the JAX-RS 2.0 library used)? I use WAS Liberty Profile and so only have access to standard JAX-RS 2.0 classes, no org.apache.cxf... classes (and I would like to avoid making my code specific to CXF other than the needed String based property for the client)

Comment: Don't forget the ```httpClientPolicy.setReadTimeout()``` as well.

Answer (score 15):

```
HTTPConduit conduit = WebClient.getConfig(webClient).getHttpConduit();
conduit.getClient().setConnectionTimeout(1000 * 3);
conduit.getClient().setReceiveTimeout(1000 * 3);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can find the correct properties in org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl:
"http.connection.timeout" and "http.receive.timeout"

So just use them as property when building the client:

```
ClientBuilder.newClient().property("http.receive.timeout", 1000);
```

With JAX-RS 2.1 (supported from CXF 3.2) you can use these standard methods in ClientBuilder:

```
connectTimeout(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);
readTimeout(long timeout, TimeUnit unit);
```

See also: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxrs-api/issues/467

Comment: In TomEE plume 7.0.4 the property settings seem to have no effect, timeout stays at about 20 seconds. `connectTimeout` and `readTimeout` are not available.

Comment: Thank you so much, the first solution works perfect in my case(wasLiberty).