# Set timeout to JAX-RS client with CXF

Tags: timeout, jax-rs, cxf

I need to set a custom timeout to the following client or configuration:

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientConfiguration;

Client client = WebClient.client(api);
ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(client);
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905685/set-timeout-for-jax-rs-client) and especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28319446/how-to-set-timeout-to-jax-rs-client-with-cxf) but I can't find those suggested property or methods in my objects. I'd rather not change the objects type.

Answer (score 0):

import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;

import org.apache.cxf.transports.http.configuration.HTTPClientPolicy;

Client client = WebClient.client(api);

HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(0);

httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(0);

http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

Comment: This was close, but I had to use the `conduit` from the `ClientConfiguration` and not the `Client`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this to the code I posted before:

```
HTTPConduit conduit = config.getHttpConduit();
conduit.getClient().setReceiveTimeout(150000);
//conduit.getClient().setConnectionTimeout(120000);
```

And it worked. I just needed to set the receive timeout, but the connection timeout setting works too.